# Finite element method for the 'Particle-In-a-Box' problem in quantum mechanics

Tags: numerical-methods, quantum-mechanics, finite-differences

(Apologies in advance for the lengthy question, but it really is needed for a precise description of what I've done!)

In suitable units, the 'Particle-in-a-box' problem is described by the following time-independant Schrodinger equation and accompanying boundary conditions:

$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = E\psi; x \in [0, 1]$

$\psi(0) = \psi(1) = 0$.

I have attempted to solve the equation numerically (as a toy problem) by replacing $\frac{d^x}{dx^2}$ with a finite difference, resulting in the following recurrence relation:

$-a\psi_{n - 1} + 2a\psi_{n} -a\psi_{n + 1} = E \psi_{n};a = \frac{1}{2\Delta{x}^2}$

which is equivalent to the following system of N linear equations in $\psi_{n}$ (when the domain of x is divided into N points $x_n$):

$-a\psi_{0} + 2a\psi_{1} - a\psi_{2} = E \psi_{1}$

$-a\psi_{1} + 2a\psi_{2} - a\psi_{2} = E \psi_{2}$

$-a\psi_{2} + 2a\psi_{3} - a\psi_{4} = E \psi_{2}$

...

$-a\psi_{N - 2} + 2a\psi_{N - 1} - a\psi_{N} = E \psi_{N - 1}$

$-a\psi_{N - 1} + 2a\psi_{N} - a\psi_{N + 1} = E \psi_{N}$.

The system of equations is equivalent to the following matrix eigenvalue problem (e.g. when the section domain between the boundaries is divided into five points):

$$H|\psi> = E|\psi>$$

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
2a & -a & 0  & 0  & 0  \\
-a & 2a & -a & 0  & 0  \\
0  & -a & 2a & -a & 0  \\
0  & 0  & -a & 2a & -a \\
0  & 0  & 0  & -a & 2a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$|\psi> = \begin{bmatrix}
\psi_{1} \\
\psi_{2} \\
\psi_{3} \\
\psi_{4} \\
\psi_{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(Where the choice $\psi_{0} = \psi_{N + 1} = 0$ encodes the boundary conditions)

I have written the following python code to solve the problem in the case where N = 100:

```
import numpy as np

# input parameters
steps = 100

# internal parameters
dx = 1.0 / float(steps - 1)
a = 1 / float(2 * dx * dx)

# prepare hamiltonian matrix
hamiltonian = np.zeros((steps, steps))

for i in range(steps):
  for j in range(steps):
    if i == j:
      hamiltonian[i, j] = 2 * a
    elif i == j + 1 or j == i + 1:
      hamiltonian[i, j] = -a
# compute and unpack results
values, vectors = np.linalg.eig(hamiltonian)
```

The computed eigenvalues are out by many orders of magnitude (e.g. expected $E_{1} \approx E_{1}^{analytical} = \frac{\pi^2}{2} = 4.9348$ (to 5sf), but got $E_{1} = 10943$ (to 5sf) and the eigenvectors, when plotted against x appeared smoothly modulated and rapidly oscillating (nothing like the expected $\sqrt(2) * sin(\pi x)$). I tried again from scratch again and again but I cannot for the life of me see what I've been doing wrong. Can anyone help me? Thank-you in advance!

Comment: Tried running your code with, say, $\mathit{steps}=2$ where you can do the computation by pencil and paper and compare?

Comment: I know nothing about the package you are using. Are the eigenvalues expected to be in increasing order? Because the number you get seems to be more or less near one of the expected eigenvalues (10941.80).

Comment: I rechecked and yeah, it turns out that I was just being stupid and the eigenvalues just require re-ordering... stupid me >.<. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following Mathematica code:

`n = 30;

 H = 
 IdentityMatrix[n]*2 - DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], -1] -  DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], 1];

 ListPlot[N[Eigenvectors[H]][[-5 ;; -1]], Joined -> True]`

This creates the Hamiltonian (without the constant factor $a$) and plots the first eigenvectors [image: image of eigenvalues]
As you can see, is works as expected, so the error should be somewhere in you code. (The creation of $H$ seems fine, so I expect it has to do something with the linear algebra part in the last line.) Or, as mentioned as a comment, it has to do something with the expected energies of the system in the theoretical result.

Comment: Thank-you! I checked over the eigenvalues and searched for the eigenvectors corresponding to the lowest few eigenvalues and they see okay-ish. Thank-you for the help!